# cURL response HTML is echoed as plain text instead of rendered HTML

Tags: php, curl

I'm POST-ing to an API endpoint that returns HTML using PHP curl. When I echo the response, it prints as plain text instead of rendering as HTML.

The headers are correct because if I echo a string of HTML, it renders normally.

Any ideas on how to make it render instead?

```php
$url = 'https://inlinestyler.torchbox.com/styler/convert/';
$myvars = 'source_url=XXXXXXXXXX&returnraw=1';

$ch = curl_init( $url );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $myvars);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$content = curl_exec( $ch );

// Plaintext
echo $content;

// Shows HTML
echo '<h1>Testing</h1>';
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you make a POST request to that API endpoint in your browser, and then check the response it gets in dev tools network panel, you will see that the API response is already in the form

```
&lt;html&gt;
&lt;head&gt;
&lt;title&gt;Example Domain&lt;/title&gt;
etc.
```

So what you get back from this API is not "pure" HTML, but HTML with the special characters `<` and `>` written as HTML entities - and *that's* why you get the code displayed, instead of a rendered result.

Applying [`html_entity_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php) to the string value you got, before outputting it via echo, will easily solve this problem.